# How to deal with multiple matches when using Regex.Replace

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a regular expression which results in multiple matches.  An example dataset would be a CSV file, and each line is an individual match:

```
product,color,type,shape,size
apple,green,fruit,round,large
banana,yellow,fruit,long,large
cherry,red,fruit,round,small
```

so match #1 would be apple,green,fruit,round,large, match #2 would be banana,yellow,fruit,long,large, etc.

So my question is, when using RegEx.Replace, how can I specify the 'starting' match (e.g., in this case, I want to start with the 2nd match), and how can I specify the # of matches after that?  This is just an example, in other scenarios, I want to start with match #4 etc.

It looks like [RegEx.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fky5t5f.aspx) supports something like this, but I am looking for a better example which applies to my scenario.

I have tried:

```
Dim r As New RegEx(pattern)
result = r.Replace(input, replace, 1, 2)
```

replace is a string which includes a captured value ($1 in my case), but I don't see any different, still get all my matches in 1 string.

Any suggestions?  I was hoping maybe something as simple as getting the # of matches, and just use a For loop.

Comment: Try [enabling `Option Strict Off`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxa04k6c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: The second parameter is not the pattern but the replacement.

Comment: Not clear what is you pattern and what is the input?

Comment: @Olivier: You are right, I messed that one up, thanks!  So I just updated my code, but it looks like the numeric values I specified have no impact.  The way I specified it, wouldn't it capture 1 match, starting with the 2nd match?

Comment: The `count` parameter denotes a character position and not a match index. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: @BradChristie: how would that help anything? It's a bad idea in any case.

Comment: @siride: It was just a link to an MSDN article with that exact problem and recommended solution.

Comment: @BradChristie: I looked at the edit history and see the original problem. Even then, turning off Option Strict is not a real solution, but a (bad) bandaid.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Regex.Replace(string, string, MatchEvaluator)`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx

This should allow you to pass a MatchEvaluator that checks the index of the particular match, so in this case you could look for `index == 1`

Comment: Ok, so I tried that example, and it just results in another error.


    Function f(m As Match)
       Console.WriteLine("executing f()")
    End Function
  
    Dim r As New RegEx(sRegExPattern)
    Dim e As MatchEvaluator = AddressOf ProcessRegExMatches
result = r.Replace("letter alphabetical missing lack release", "\w+", e)
  
I get:
Script compile error: Method 'Public Function ProcessRegExMatches(m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) As Object' does not have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Function MatchEvaluator(match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) As String'

Comment: I included the cost in the post above yours, but the site doesn't let me format code in responses.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Regex just to indentify lines in a text. Read the CSV-file with

```
Dim lines As String()

lines = File.ReadAllLines("path of the CSV file")
```

Then loop like this

```
For i As Integer = starting_match To last_match
    lines(i) = lines(i).Replace("old","new")
Next
```

And put the lines together with

```
Dim result As String
result = String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines)
```

---

**UPDATE**

The confusion comes from the fact that the starting position in the `Replace` method denotes a starting character position and not a starting match index. Therefore I suggest using this extension method

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function ReplaceMatches(regex As Regex,
                                      input As String, replacement As String, 
                                      countMatches As Integer, startAtMatch As Integer
                                     ) As String
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(input)
    If startAtMatch >= matches.Count Then
        Return input
    End If
    Dim skippedMatch As Match = matches(startAtMatch - 1)
    Dim startAtCharacterPosition As Integer = skippedMatch.Index + skippedMatch.Length
    Return regex.Replace(input, replacement, countMatches, startAtCharacterPosition)
End Function
```

Now you can replace with:

```
Dim input As String = "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff"
Dim startAtMatch As Integer = 2 ' ccc
Dim countMatches As Integer = 3

Dim regex = New Regex("\w+")
Dim result As String = regex.ReplaceMatches(input, "XX", countMatches, startAtMatch)
Console.WriteLine(result) ' --> "aaa bbb XX XX XX fff"
```

(Examples converted from C# to VB with [devloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/))

Comment: Well this was just an example, it isn't always a CSV file (in fact, in most cases it isn't even a file), it could be a bunch of HTML, where I am trying to capture <li> groups.

Answer (score -2):

Following code might help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

```
Imports System.Collections

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Example

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim words As String = "letter alphabetical missing lack release " + _
                              "penchant slack acryllic laundry cease"
        Dim pattern As String = "\w+  # Matches all the characters in a word."
        Dim evaluator As MatchEvaluator = AddressOf WordScrambler
        Console.WriteLine("Original words:")
        Console.WriteLine(words)
        Console.WriteLine("Scrambled words:")
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(words, pattern, evaluator,
                                        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
    End Sub

    Public Function WordScrambler(ByVal match As Match) As String
        Dim arraySize As Integer = match.Value.Length - 1
        ' Define two arrays equal to the number of letters in the match. 
        Dim keys(arraySize) As Double
        Dim letters(arraySize) As Char

        ' Instantiate random number generator' 
        Dim rnd As New Random()

        For ctr As Integer = 0 To match.Value.Length - 1
            ' Populate the array of keys with random numbers.
            keys(ctr) = rnd.NextDouble()
            ' Assign letter to array of letters.
            letters(ctr) = match.Value.Chars(ctr)
        Next
        Array.Sort(keys, letters, 0, arraySize, Comparer.Default)
        Return New String(letters)
    End Function

End Module

' The example displays output similar to the following: 
'    Original words: 
'    letter alphabetical missing lack release penchant slack acryllic laundry cease 
'     
'    Scrambled words: 
'    etlert liahepalbcat imsgsni alkc ereelsa epcnnaht lscak cayirllc alnyurd ecsae
```